# Verifying properties using Solver

Tags: algorithm, solver, smt

I have a system of equations of the form:

x1 * x2 *.... * xn = a,  where * can either be + or - .

I am building some other equation of the same form, and I want to verify 
if they are satisfied by the first system.

My question is: Is there a solver that can affirm whether the given equation is satisfied or not?

Many thanks,
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) with a bias (you need to end up one subset larger than the other by `a`, instead of them being equal). It can be addressed by adding `a` to the set, and now solve "regular" partition problem.

This problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), but can be solved in pseudo-polynomial time using dynamic programming:

```
D(x,i) = false   x<0
D(0,i) = true
D(x,0) = false   x != 0
D(x,i) = D(x,i-1) OR D(x-arr[i],i-1)
```

And you are looking for a subset of sum `(x1 + x2 + ... + xn + a) / 2`

The idea is to get 2 sets, one with `a` (let it be `A`) and one without it (let it be `B`).

Give all the elements (except `a`) in `A` `-` sign, and all elements in `B` a `+` sign.

Since sum(A) = sum(B), you get

```
sum(B)-(sum(A)-a) = sum(B) - sum(A) + a = 0 + a = a
```